# Are the modifiers of Shields of Cthulhu set per night?

Tags: terraria

Are the modifiers of Shields of Cthulhu set per night?

I fought 3 Eyes of Cthulhu in one night, and all of their Treasure Bags got me Warding Shields of Cthulhu.

I'm Softcore in a Expert Large world on PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loot bags in Terraria are totally random, and its contents are chosen by an RNG (Random Number Generator)

In your case, you just got lucky. Loot bags contents depend on the boss it comes from and is then chosen with an RNG, along with any modifiers the loot may have, and is not dependent or chosen with the cycles of night and day... which is rather unfortunate... because it would make it so easy to get good loot.

But, I suppose that's exactly why that's not the case.

I should also mention that being on Normal or Expert mode does not affect the chances of getting loot, nor does it affect what kind of modifiers will be placed upon the loot, Normal mode having the same generation, but only without the bag to hold all the loot, the loot being immediately generated upon the death of the boss, while Expert mode itself only adds extra loot to the generation table, I.E. The Shield of Cthulhu that is available in Expert mode, but not Normal mode.

Comment: Isn't it true that the loot bag from the eye of cthulu will always contain a shield of cthulu? So not that RNG in this case. Next to that some loot has a better chance of spawning in Expert mode.

Comment: Yes, it is true the Eye Of Cthulu loot bag will always contain the Shield Of Cthulu, however, the modifier placed upon it is chosen by an RNG, and along with the Shield Of Cthulu, Crimtane Ore/Demonite Ore, Crimson Seeds/Corrupt Seeds Unholy Arrow, and Lesser Healing Potion all have a 100% drop chance, but the amount that is dropped is chosen by an RNG. Like most loot bags, but really is mainly RNG.

Comment: It should be noted that loot bags contain the same drops as the boss normally would have, except each player gets their own bag. This means that you definitely *do* get more loot in multiplayer. [Additionally, bosses **do** drop a higher loot quantity on Expert, even when alone](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Expert_mode), and expert mode roughly doubles the drop chance for many unique gear items dropped by regular enemies (such as the Pixie's chance to drop a Fast Clock). Of course, a loot bag uses the same RNG for modifiers as any other drop source.